# connect to my sql database via python

Tags: python, mysql, database, connector

i'm trying to insert values in mysql database using python on windows 10. I've downloaded mysql-connector-python-2.0.4-py2.7 .

This is my python code :

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
                  user="root",
                  passwd="1234",
                  db="iot")
x = conn.cursor()

try:
   x.execute("""INSERT INTO sensors VALUES (%s,%s)""",(25,300))
   conn.commit()
except:
   conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

when I run the code I'm getting this error :

```
IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\enwan\Anaconda\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 235, in asyncqueue
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Users\enwan\Anaconda\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 334, in putmessage
    raise IOError, "socket no longer exists"
IOError: socket no longer exists
```

Any help ?

Comment: Probably your _mysql server_ is not working... try to connect manually using __mycli__ to check if everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your MySQL is running. Check it under services and start.